# Get and then set a value in the registry using VBS

Tags: vbscript, registry

I'm trying to retrieve the proxy override list from the registry so that I can add local entries from my hosts file to it.

To do this I am using `LocalClass_StdRegProv.GetStringValue(path, key)`, but I cannot seem to get the correct value.

The below code yeilds no errors, but the value of `override` is simply `0`.

What am I doing wrong?

The script is then telling me there was an error with setting the value back to registry, which is somewhat to be expected if it's trying to set a string value to an integer, but if I'm doing that wrong as well I'd apprciate the heads up. Thanks.

```
'** Set the HKCU as a constant *'
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

Dim LocalClass_StdRegProv
Set LocalClass_StdRegProv = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")

'** Set the proxy override list *'
Dim overrideList(1)
overrideList(0) = "local.latestwordpress.com"
overrideList(1) = "local.fileshare.com"

'** Set the proxy override string to include entries from localhost *'
Dim result, override
override = LocalClass_StdRegProv.GetStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", "ProxyOverride")
override = updateOverride(override, overrideList)
result = LocalClass_StdRegProv.SetStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", "ProxyOverride", override)
checkResult(result)

'** Reset the objects *'
Call resetObjects

'** Quit the script *'
WScript.Quit


'**
 ' Update the proxy override list (if required) to include any local sites
 '
 ' @param required string override      The proxy override string to check
 ' @param required array overrideList   A list of addresses to include in the proxy override list
 '*
Function updateOverride(override, overrideList)

    Dim item

    '** Loop through each item in the override list... *'
    For Each item In overrideList

        '** Check to see if the current item is missing from the proxy override string... *'
        If Not InStr(override, item) Then
            override = item & ";" & override    ' Add the current to the proxy override string
        End If

    Next

    updateOverride = override

End Function


'**
 ' Check the result of a Registry key edit to ensure that it was valid
 '
 ' @param required integer result   The result of the Registry key edit to check
 '*
Function checkResult(result)

    '** Check to see if there is a VBS error or if the regestry set failed *'
    If Err.Number <> 0 Or result <> 0 Then

        '** Display an error message to the user *'
        Dim message, title
        message = "An error occured while updating your proxy settings." & vbCrLf & vbCrlF & "In order to use the internet you must manually set your proxy settings via Internet Explorer."
        title = "Error setting proxy"
        MsgBox message, vbCritical, title

        '** Reset the objects *'
        Call resetObjects

        '** Quit the script *'
        WScript.Quit

    End If

End Function


'**
 ' Reset the objects that have been used in this script
 '*
Function resetObjects()

    Set LocalClass_StdRegProv = Nothing

End Function
```

**Edit** - Added missing declaration of HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: I don't see a definition for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` in your code.

Comment: Good spot.  It does exist in reality (and has been added now), but the above code is abridged and I accidently removed that definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `override` is always `0` because you're calling `GetStringValue` incorrectly. This:

```
override = LocalClass_StdRegProv.GetStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", "ProxyOverride")
```

Should be this:

```
LocalClass_StdRegProv.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", "ProxyOverride", override
```

i.e. the 4th parameter is an `out` parameter as stated in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The return value from `GetStringValue` actually indicates success/failure

The rest looks ok, in that `result` will be `0` if the write performed by `SetStringValue` was successful

Comment: Thank you sir, that does the job. To my shame, I'd actually reviewed the docs but still not realised what I'd done!